# Installing runtime for business network undefined. ...Error: Error trying install composer runtime

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm facing this problem to when I try to deploy my network

$ composer network deploy -a tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna  -A admin -S adminpw -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -f networkadmin.card
Deploying business network from archive: tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna
Business network definition:
        Identifier: tutorial-network
        Description: Blockchain network for practicing purposes.

Installing runtime for business network undefined. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install composer runtime. Error: The Composer runtime is already installed on all the peers
Command failed

I've these images running

```
peer0.org1.example.com
couchdb
ca.org1.example.com
orderer.example.com
```

Then if I do as in the [Developer Tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html)

This is what I have.

$ composer network start --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --archiveFile tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna --file networkadmin.card
Starting business network from archive: tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna
Business network definition:
        Identifier: tutorial-network@0.0.1
        Description: Blockchain network for practiving purposes.

Processing these Network Admins:
        userName: admin

â Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to instantiate composer runtime. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Error starting container: **Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/**: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

I don't know why is getting this error Error: Error starting container: **Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/** 
I have all images running or I think they are.

Any idea? Pleasee I'm almost frustrated.

Comment: Check the peer logs (docker logs <peer container id>, it sounds like the peer cannot contact the docker hub to download the ccenv image it needs.

Comment: Yes I've managed to fix it looking at my peer logs. and that was all. fabric-tools cli, javaenv, zookeeper and baseos images were missing (I didn't know) and my peers were unable to contact docker hub. All I did was to run bootstrap.sh script and it did all the magic. Course tutorials didn't work for me.   Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use Bootstrap script from [Hyperledger Fabric at github](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.0/scripts/bootstrap-1.0.4.sh) in my case bootstrap-1.0.4.sh fixed the problem, that is the version I'm running.